# Sqlalchemy and pgpool-II - OperationalError

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pgpool

Today I set up pgpool-II on one of my company servers for database replication purposes and I'm trying to connect to it from my application located on another server. Previously it connected to database on the same server where pgpool is now installed without problems - I just needed to provide something like this link in config file:

database: postgresql://user:password@host:port/db_name

I have changed port to the one on which pgpool listens for connections and provided user and password from pcp.conf, but then I get a list of errors after starting app, all of them of the same type:

OperationalError: (OperationalError) unable to open database file None None

Doesn't matter if I'm authenticating as postgresql or pgpool user and if I provide md5 encrypted or plaintext password, errors are the same. How can I properly connect to my database then?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved days ago, needed to change administrative database in pgpool config from "template1" to "postgres". IDK why it doesn't default to that.